# Odoo 9 add column to grid view

Tags: view, odoo, odoo-9

I'm create simple module with 4 fields (name,date,user,description).Below is my .xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
        <data>

            <record id="view_my_report_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">penalty.form</field>
            <field name="model">my.report</field>
            <field eval="2" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Project">

                    <sheet string="My report">

                    <group>
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h1 class="o_row">
                               <field name="name" placeholder="Name..." />
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="user" placeholder="User..."/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="date" placeholder="Date..."/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page name="description_page" string="Description">
                           <field name="description"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_my_report_form">
            <field name="name">Add new</field>
            <field name="res_model">my.report</field>
        </record>
      <menuitem name="MY report" id="menu_penalty" action="action_my_izvjestaj_form" sequence="1"/>    
    </data>
</openerp>
```

When open from menu in grid view visble is only name.

https://postimg.org/image/ccms5aww3/

How add date and user fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare Tree view for that model.

```
<!-- Tree Views BEGIN-->
  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_my_report_tree">
     <field name="name">penalty.tree</field>
     <field name="model">my.form</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Project">
           <field name="name"/>
           <field name="user"/>
           <field name="date"/>
        </tree>
     </field>
  </record>
```